# Open Git Repository in Neatbeans using SmartGit

Tags: git, netbeans, smartgit

I am trying to open a branch in a Git repository and my IDE (Netbeans) isn't recognizing it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to the command line and check your branches:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git branch -avvv
```

Then check what branches you see on NetBeans with  `Netbeans. -> Get -> Branch -> Switch To Branch`.
([as detailed here, be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845281/6309))